# Как заменить значения индексов фрейма данных по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Хочу выполнить следующую последовательность действий:

- Из имеющегося фрейма данных надо взять по условию индекса только нужные мне данные
- Заменить значения индексов по условию другими, нужными мне значениями

С первым пунктом получилось справиться успешно, но со 2 ерунда какая-то получается.

```
d   N1  N2  N3
aa  12  12  5
bb  27  29  25
cc  26  27  18
aa  23  31  20
bb  24  25  23
cc  27  17  33
aa  22  18  28
bb  23  24  20
cc  21  19  19
```

Получилось сделать только как-то так, но подозреваю, что есть способ гораздо коороче, да и этот способ дает дубликат столбца с индексом:

```
df = pd.read_excel('BB.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист10')
df.loc[df['d'] == 'cc', 'd'] = 'data1'
df.loc[df['d'] == 'aa', 'd'] = 'data2'
df.set_index(df['d'],inplace=True)
df_torg = df.loc[df.index.isin(['data1','data2'])]
df_torg.set_index(df_torg['d'],inplace=True)
```

Вот, [что было и вот что хочу](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10ePjLNa1AQVDv1rF3CP5tTWE8WG6miXQ9i4GPbcS4EA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: вы можете привести в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить?

Comment: готово. Добавлено

Comment: Вас попросили привести ожидаемый результат **в вопросе**, а вы опубликовали его в гугле. Смею вас уверить, в гугле ожидаемый вами результат не интересует никого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapping = {"cc": "data1", "aa": "data2"}

idx = list(mapping.keys())

res = df.query("data in @idx").reset_index().replace(mapping).set_index("data")
```

результат:

```
In [90]: res
Out[90]:
       N1  N2  N3
data
data2  12  12   5
data1  26  27  18
data2  23  31  20
data1  27  17  33
data2  22  18  28
data1  21  19  19
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как можно сделать этот столбец data индексовым, чтобы он не дублировался? У меня почему-то получаются дубли, когда пытаюсь

Comment: А еще- по каким ключевым словам прогуглить можно тот метод, которым вы делали замены "cc" на "data1" и тд? например, если у меня несколько значений, которые нужно одинаково обозвать, мне их каждый раз отдельно прописывать или можно перечислить один раз

Comment: @IoIo, замены - это `pandas replace` ...